Can I search multiple element types in one query?
Yup, this is a repeat of a question from 7 years ago. The github discussion seems to have died out 2 years ago.
I can't do weird array merging due to pagination which accepts an element query. So it needs to be a single query.
I want a site search that will return entries and Shopify products. I can't be the first person to try doing this.

The answer is still “no”.
I don’t think the desire to add the feature has died out, even if the GitHub discussion feels somewhat stale. It was on the roadmap not too long ago but I no longer see it there. Why don’t you revive the discussion? It still seems like a much (and long) requested feature that would be very handy to have.

I haven't tried this myself, but a potential workaround would be to execute the separate queries (unpaginated), merge them all and then sort by score, and then do pagination afterwards using the create function like this: https://gist.github.com/juban/a55781d49f2f68ec3ca47979bcaaa49a
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#create
(When encountering this problem myself in the past, so far I've always managed to get away with a (very large) non-paginated result set, grouped by types ("types" might be category groups, entry sections, product groups, or assets etc). Typically I arrange those types visually into tabs - this makes it more obvious that each tab is effectively a new 'relevance context'.
